# From Eisenbud, why is $g(\mathfrak{m}_x)=\mathfrak{m}_{g^{-1}x}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is from Section 1.7, page 38 of Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra.

Here $X$ is an algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $G$ is a group acting on $X$ by polynomial maps. The space of $A(X)^G$ denotes the $G$-invariant elements of the coordinate ring $A(X)$ of $X$. Since $A(X)^G$ is affine, $A(X)^G=A(Y)$ for some variety $Y$. The inclusion map $A(Y)\to A(X)$ induces a morphism of varieties $\pi\colon X\to Y$.

Eisenbud wants to show $\pi$ is constant on $G$-orbits, and to do so he writes $g(\mathfrak{m}_x)=\mathfrak{m}_{g^{-1}x}$, where $x$ is a point of $X$, and $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is the corresponding ideal of $A(X)$.

If $A(X)=k[X_1,\dots,X_n]/I(X)$ for some polynomial algebra, and concretely $X\subseteq k^n$, then if $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a point, $\mathfrak{m}_x=(X_1-x_1,\dots,X_n-x_n)+I(X)$. It's not clear to me what the $G$-action is here, because Eisenbud lets $G$ act on the left of $X$, but then has $G$ act on $A(X)$ by $g\cdot f=f\circ g$, which isn't a left action. Adjusting the action as $g\cdot f=f\circ g^{-1}$, seems like $g\cdot(X_i-x_i)=X_i\circ g^{-1}-gx_i$. Do this functions generate $\mathfrak{m}_{g^{-1}x}$?

Answer (score 1):

I observed it as following:
The key point is that the condidtion "$G$ acts by polynomial maps".

I considered the example:
$X=k[u,v]/(v^2-u^3-u)$ and $g∈G$ acts on $X$ by sending $(a,b) \to (-a,ib)$.
[More precisely, it sends the prime ideal $(u-a,v-b) \to (u+a,v-ib)$.]

Then $g∈G$ acts on $A[X]$ by sending $f(u,v) \to f(-u,iv)$.

Thus, $g$ sends $u-a \to -u-a$, $v-b \to iv-b$.

So it sends $m_x = (u-a,v-b) \to (-u-a,iv-b) = (u+a,v+ib)$,
which correspond to $m_{g^{-1}x}$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is a typo. You're right, $G$ acts on $A(X)$ by $g \cdot f=f \circ g^{-1}$, so that $g \cdot \mathfrak{m}_x$ ($\mathfrak{m}_x$ corresponds to $x \in X$) is equal to $\mathfrak{m}_{g(x)}$ (which corresponds to $g(x) \in X$). Fortunately in this case it has no influence on the conclusion.

To complete my answer : if $X$ is seen as $X=V(I) \subset k^n$, then $g\cdot (x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ can be written as $(P_1^g(x),\cdots,P_n^g(x))$ for $P_i^g \in k[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ and where $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$. Seeing $x$ as the ideal $(X_1-x_1,\cdots,X_n-x_n)+I$, the ideal corresponding to $g(x)$ would be $(X_1-P_1^g(x),\cdots,X_n-P_n^g(x))+I$